# How does one design load tests for a website?

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing

I've recently been thinking how to test the performance of our webapps before we put them live. I know that we can't replicate actual user activities for this test because it's new functionality. I can make some guesses about user activity by looking at our logs, and create tests accordingly, but I wonder what this will achieve.

I'm keen to know how one can:

1. determine the load and
2. determine the behaviour

How far will this get you in comparing with a real world scenario?

Answer (score 5):

Vast question. We have been running benchmarks and load test for several years at my company, mostly HTTP based.

Before getting into complex scenarios, we often start with simple benchmarks based on **Apache Bench** (the 'ab' command bundled with Apache). This is not a load test but a performance one, since the generated client actually wait for the HTTP query completion before proceeding to the next. The basic idea is to try 'ab -c N -t 30' with N=1,2,4,8,50,100 (for instance). You quickly get an idea of the scalability and the maximum throughput you should expect.

**Note**: run the 'ab' command near the test server (ideally on the same LAN), otherwise you'll also bench the network (latency being the main issue here). But in some business cases this is the overall system (server + network) which is really meant to be tested.

From here, if the results look good (ie. the througput scales up to the number of processors on the server side, low or zero error rate), we proceed to load testing. Otherwise we **search for bottlenecks** since the load test will only confirm the scalability problem *and* most probably show horrible results once the load is larger than the supported throughput (100% of 500 internal errors, connection drops, large timouts, server thrashing, etc).

BTW, by load testing I mean using tools which can apply **any load an a given server/app**, especially a load the server cannot handle (eg: Jmeter, Tsung). What's very interesting in a load test is observing what's happening when the server is overloaded. Determining the maximum load the server can handle is up to you, when you choose the exact test point where the performances are not deemed acceptable.

Then it's a matter of guessing or observing existing patterns. In many cases we are asked to perform a load test for a new website, where obviously no real behaviour has been observed. Otherwise you can use analytics and obseve the top ten pages : your scenario should at least traverse them. You'll want some navigation paths which:

- obviously reach the home page
- use the search feature and bounce from one content to the other, maybe randomly
- proceed to login if the feature exists
- more generally exercice POST forms, loadtest which only read/GET data are not very meaningful

Other tips:

- avoid complexity; for instance if you have a shopping cart, you don't have to set up a real shopping scenario with payment et al. On an e-commerce shop, the shopping cart path is rarely a performance problem, 95% of the traffic is elsewhere (browsing products, etc).
- test navigation paths one by one before piling them up in one big load test fiesta; they should provide good result individually beforehand
- it's better to sollicitate many paths to really exercice caches (there always are caches: HTTP, app, SQL, filesystem, etc); tools which generate dynamic scenarii where you can change login names or object IDs from long lists are a must

The overall idea is to do it incrementally, starting from simple tests, otherwise you'll have a hard time interpreting result if they're not fitting a perfect scalability curve. And guess what? They never fit a perfect scalability curve...

Answer (score 0):

1. It's determined by business. [About SLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) It's usually marks as "100% load". Tests can be also 200% or more if you want find max system performance or how system alive load peak or very long 100% test if you want to know system stability.
2. Rule exist that tell 20% of all operations take 80% of times. Use user statistics to determine needed actions. Else scenario is determined by business again. User activity could change (set of operations) during time(day/night, week, end of month and so on), so you must create different profiles of user activity.